# find files with certain pattern and ignore others

Tags: find

I have files like:

```
1_script1.sql
2_script2.sql
script1.sql
script2.sql
```

I would like to use `find` to get the files only `1_script1.sql` and `2_script2.sql` and also use the owner of the file to filter them.

```
find . -type f -user oracle -name "\{1..99\}_test*.sql"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The patterns used by `find`'s `-name` and `-path` are simple shell glob ones where only `?`, `*` and `[...]` are recognised (and `\` as an escape operator). Even the `-regex` supported (in incompatible ways) by a few `find` implementations don't have number range operators.

To express numbers from 1 to 99 expressed on one or 2 digits with basic glob patterns, you need `[1-9]` or `[0-9][0-9]` (assuming the C locale for `[0-9]` to be the same as `[0123456789]` and accept file names with arbitrary byte values) and exclude `00`, so:

```
LC_ALL=C find . '(' -name '[1-9]_test*.sql' -o \
                    -name '[0-9][0-9]_test*.sql' \
                ')' ! -name '00_*' -type f -user oracle
```

(putting the `-name` checks first as they are cheaper to perform than the ones like `-type` or `-user` which need or may need to retrieve file metadata; some `find` implementations do the reordering internally as an optimisation)

Or you could use `zsh` whose globs have a `<x-y>` decimal-integer-number-range operator and supports recursive globbing and glob qualifiers:

```
print -rC1 -- **/<1-100>_test*.sql(NDn.u[oracle])
```

(here allowing numbers 1 to 100 expressed in any number of digits like `000023_testing.sql`; and you get sorting (numerical with `n`) as a bonus, though you could disable it with the `oN` qualifier).

Another approach would be to use `perl`'s `File::Find`:

```
perl -MFile::Find -le '
  @user = getpwnam "oracle" or die "oracle user unknown\n";
  find(sub {
         if (/^(\d+)_test.*\.sql\z/s && $1 >= 1 && $1 <= 100) {
           if (@s = lstat$_) {
             print "File::Find::name if -f _ && $s[4] == $user[2];
           } else {warn "$_: $!\n"}
         }
       }, @ARGV)' -- .
```

Comment: Thank You, I got the desired result from the command. It worked  even after removing '(' in command.       find . -name '[1-9]_test*.sql' -o -name '[0-9][0-9]_test*.sql' ! -name '00_*' -type f -user oracle

Comment: @srikantht, removing the `'('` would make it like `LC_ALL=C find .  -name '[1-9]_test*.sql' -o '(' -name '[0-9][0-9]_test*.sql' ! -name '00_*' -type f -user oracle ')'` because of how associativity works with the `-o` and `-a` (implied) boolean operators so would **not** be what you want as the `-type f` and `-user oracle` would not apply to files with single digit numbers.